# Flash at end of looped gif?

Tags: html, css, gif

I'm encountering a white flash at the end of a looping gif in an html document. I'm displaying the gif as a background image because I want it to tile. The individual frames all look fine, there is no white frame at the end.

Does anyone have an encoding or code-based solution? I'm using the legacy "save for web" feature in Photoshop. The reason I'm not using .webp or another modern animation format is that I want the classic dithered gif look.

Here's the link: [www.natehess.com/index.html](http://www.natehess.com/index.html)

The gif is too large to upload here, but here's a link: [www.natehess.com/fractal.gif](http://www.natehess.com/fractal.gif)

Thanks!

```html
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0px;    
    }
    .splash {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-image: url(http://www.natehess.com/fractal.gif);
        border: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="splash"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your gif basicly has this « white » flash or last white frame. So you will need to edit gif duration to fix it. Because that means that duration > animation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your frame 393 is white.

I used https://ezgif.com/ to remove the frame and optimize it from 3MB to 1.7MB

```html
<html>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  .splash {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHfNO.gif);
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="splash"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: appreciate the help mplunjan. the white frame was a glitch from the photoshop render. i was working with an image sequence in the glitched version. i made the frames into an mp4 instead, loaded it to photoshop and it exported correctly.